# Colocar fecha actual en un TextBox en C#

Tags: c#, html, mvc

Necesito que en el `TextBox` se me cargue la fecha actual; lo estoy haciendo con el siguiente código pero al ejecutarlo no me carga ninguna fecha:

```
<td>
    <label for="Fecha">Fecha:</label>
</td>
<td>                            
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Facturas.Fecha, new { @class = "form-control  input-sm", @Type= "date", value = System.DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString()})
</td>
```

Utilizo C# MVC.

Comment: Podrías inicializar en tu modelo la propiedad Facturas.Fecha a DateTime.Now. Así automáticamente se establece el dato en la vista.

Answer (score 2):

En tu modelo puedes poner un valor por defecto, en este caso, la fecha actual usando `get { return DateTime.Now; }`, suponiendo que la propiedad se llama `FechaActual`:

```
public DateTime FechaActual { 
    get { return DateTime.Now; } 
    set { this.FechaActual = value; } 
}
```

En la vista, no debes realizar ninguna modificación, simplemente poner la propiedad del modelo de la siguiente forma:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FechaActual, new {@class="form-control"})
```

Aquí puedes ver la <kbd>[demostración de la solución](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NrCeL5)</kbd>.

Comment: Hola @Flxtr,  Mejorando el código que has escrito, yo eliminaria la parte del set{}. Si FechaActual devuelve la fecha del sistema, no tiene mucho sentido el establecerla. :)

Comment: @Sergio sí, suena lógico, aunque preferí dejarlo para que el OP lo tomé a su consideración.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar la propiedad Today:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
```

Revisa la documentación: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today(v=vs.110).aspx